# How to Inflate a layout in fragment in onReceivedError

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show/inflate a layout with a refresh button in my `Fragment` in `onReceivedError`..
I can't figure out that...

Answer (score 0):

So in `onReceivedError` of Fragment you should replace this Fragment with itself

Happy Coding!!

Comment: With itself? Wouldn't it go on for endless time

Comment: Nope buddy replace fragment with iteself only when you want to refresh

Comment: @Sanoop What kind of things you edit in my answer ? if you want to gain 2 points tell me i will give you a lot

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13843419), You wanted to get deleted by others for beiing a low quality post? BTW a lot of people tagged your answer as :Low Quality Post

Comment: you are just capitalize text nothing else !!! Seriously Poor programmer Go for Testing dude it will defiantly suits you

Comment: Sure, Advice taken into consideration (Y)